# AWS SCP , enforce tagging for EC2 and allow specific AWS Backup service role to restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-policies, aws-backup, aws-scp

I have a tag enforcement scp that deny ec2 creation without `CodeDomaine` Tag except for AWS Backup service:

```
"Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
      "ec2:RunInstances"
    ],
    
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
      "Null": {
        "aws:RequestTag/CodeDomaine": "true"
      },
      "StringNotLike": {
        "aws:PrincipalArn": [
          "arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole/AWSBackup-AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

I want to allow AWS backup service to restore when needed but i get this error:

```
DecodedMessage": "{\"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":true,\"matchedStatements\":{\"items\":[{\"statementId\":\"DenyEC2CreationSCP1\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"AROAY56UJVB4...\"}]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*\"},{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"aws:PrincipalArn\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole/*\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:RequestTag/CodeDomaine\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"true\"}]}}]}}]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{\"principal\":{\"id\":\"AROAY56UJ...:AWSBackup-AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:sts::<accountID>:assumed-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole/AWSBackup-AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole\"},\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-3:<accountID>:instance/*\",\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"ec2:InstanceMarketType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"on-demand\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Resource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"instance/*\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Account\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"<accountID>\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:AvailabilityZone\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"eu-west-3b\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:ebsOptimized\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:InstanceType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"t2.medium\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:RootDeviceType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ebs\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:InstanceProfile\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:instance-profile/autodesk-dev\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"eu-west-3\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Service\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:InstanceID\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"*\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:Type\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"instance\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:Tenancy\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"default\"}]}},{\"key\":\"ec2:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"eu-west-3\"}]}},{\"key\":\"aws:ARN\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-3:<accountID>:instance/*\"}]}}]}}}"
```

}

I tried many solutions to adjust the SCP conditions but no way!!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !
have to specify the role RNA and not the session RNA (ex : arn:aws:iam::*:role/OrganizationAdminRole)

```
"Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
      "ec2:RunInstances"
    ],
    
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
      "Null": {
        "aws:RequestTag/CodeDomaine": "true"
      },
      "StringNotLike": {
        "aws:PrincipalArn": [
          "arn:aws:iam::*:role/service-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).